# Auto-resizing NSScrollView that wraps an NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How do I tell an `NSScrollView` that wraps an `NSTextView` to grow with the `NSTextView` until a maximum?

== In more details:

The UI is common in many messanger/chat app. Initially, the `NSTextView` is empty and has just enough height to show one line of text. The `NSScrollView` is just enough to fit the `NSTextView`. As the user type in more text, the `NSScrollView` should grow along with the `NSTextView`, until reaching a maximum height, then start showing the vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe `NSTextStorageDidProcessEditingNotification` on the text storage of the text view. Then call `usedRectForTextContainer` on the layout manager to determine how large the text is for the view's text container.

You may also need to add `extraLineFragmentRect` to it, I'm not sure. That's also available from the layout manager.

Comment: Well, actually the `NSTextView` can auto-resize itself, just check the "Resizable - Vertically" checkbox in IB. However, the wrapping `NSScrollView` doesn't resize itself. That's why the scroll bar show up.

Comment: Right so just figure out how big the text is, by asking the layout manager, and then resize the scroll view to that height.

Comment: Text view's auto resizing is complicated/unreliable. It tries to avoid making the layout manager work hard so it will simply grab the metrics for however many lines of text are visible, then stops. While your app is idle it gradually tells the layout manager to do more font glyph size calculations, growing the text view in small chunks. This can take _minutes_ to finish depending how much content there is, and there's no way to know when it's finished. However if you ask the layout manager how tall the contents are, it will do the entire thing straight away.